# Check for occurence in both categories

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with two columns `source` and `id`. I want to check which of the ids in the `id` column are present in both categories of the column `source`.

Here is an example:

```
dd <- read.table(text="
source id
a      1
a      2
a      3
b      1
b      3
b      4", 
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

For this example i want to get the ids 1 and 3 because they occur in both categories.

Is there a way to retrieve all the ids with e.g. dplyr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 filter(n_distinct(source) == 2)

  source    id
  <chr>  <int>
1 a          1
2 a          3
3 b          1
4 b          3
```

If there could be n categories:

```
df %>%
 mutate(n_dist = n_distinct(source)) %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 filter(n_distinct(source) == n_dist) %>%
 select(-n_dist)
```

Or a somehow less-tidy version:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 filter(n_distinct(source) == n_distinct(df$source))
```

Comment: consider `>= 2` instead of `== 2`, in case there are duplicates within a letter.

Comment: nice. `dd %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(n()>1)` comes also to the solution if there is indeed no duplicate id per source